# How to display a value for a TextField with a fixed height

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

If I put down a specific value for height, then my value for the text field moves somewhere, I can't understand why.

[image]

But if I don't set the height values, then everything is displayed in order

[image]

Here is my code:

```
            Row(
                verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
//                    .size(40.dp)
                    .background(color = LightGray20, shape = RoundedCornerShape(6.dp))
                    .padding(6.dp)
            ) {
                TextField(
                    modifier = Modifier.width(80.dp),
//                        .height(28.dp),
                    value = product.quantity.toString(),
                    onValueChange = {
                        it.toDoubleOrNull()?.let { value -> quantityChangeHandler(product, value) }
                    },
                    textStyle = LocalTextStyle.current.copy(textAlign = TextAlign.End, fontSize = 16.sp),
                    maxLines = 1,
                    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
                        keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number,
                        imeAction = ImeAction.Done
                    ),
                    keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(
                        onDone = { localFocusManager.clearFocus() }
                    ),
                    shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp),
                    colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
                        focusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
                        unfocusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
                        disabledIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
                    ),
                )
                Text(
                    text = description,
                    fontSize = 16.sp,
                    maxLines = 1,
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 2.dp)
                )
            }
```

Here is the my design what i want to do:

[image]

Here what i find about paddings:

[image]

Comment: Did you try to change the text size?

Comment: Yep, in textStyle - fontSize

Comment: It seems that the height is not enough for the text to show up. I think that you should remove the inner paddings.

Comment: @momt99 paddings in `Row`? but i need this padding.

Comment: No, the default `TextField` sticks to the material design with the defined margins. There's a dense decoration for it which has a reduced margin. But as you need more control over the design, `BasicTextField` is maybe what you are looking for.